# How can I get DispatcherTimer to set a timer longer than 24 days?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

My code uses `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` to set a timer.

One day I found myself trying to set a larger timer than usual, and I got an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: TimeSpan period must be less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.
```

However, even in the 100ns units ("ticks") used by .NET `TimeSpan`s, my value (roughly 41 days & 15½ hours, or 3,598,196,944 ms, or 3.5981969e+13 ticks — admittedly, a lot of ticks) ought to be well within the range of a 64-bit integer, which is what the documentation claims that [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) uses internally (and which is used by  the `TimeSpan` constructor taking ticks).

Since `Int32.MaxValue` is 2,147,483,647, it is suggested that [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.8) only supports durations up to almost 25 days. But the `DispatcherTimer` documentation does not mention this limitation.

I ran some tests, and indeed:

```
#include <cstdint>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Threading;

void tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ args) {}

int main()
{
    // Duration is in 100ns units (10m per second).
    const TimeSpan delay1(2147483647ULL * 10000);

    const TimeSpan delay2(2147483648ULL * 10000);

    // Fine
    DispatcherTimer^ timer1 = gcnew DispatcherTimer(
        delay1,
        DispatcherPriority::Normal,
        gcnew EventHandler(&tick),
        Dispatcher::CurrentDispatcher
    );

    // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    DispatcherTimer^ timer2 = gcnew DispatcherTimer(
        delay2,
        DispatcherPriority::Normal,
        gcnew EventHandler(&tick),
        Dispatcher::CurrentDispatcher
    );
}
```

I mean, okay, I can work around it by sequentially setting shorter delays (of, say, a maximum of a day at a time) but I'd like to avoid that complexity if possible.

Are my observations accurate? If so, is there any way to change this undocumented behaviour?

*[Windows 10 (v1803), Visual Studio 2019 (v16.4.5), .NET 4.7.03056, x64 build]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When documentation fails, let's take a look at ye olde source code:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer.cs,94

```cs
if (interval.TotalMilliseconds > Int32.MaxValue)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("interval", SR.Get(SRID.TimeSpanPeriodOutOfRange_TooLarge));
```

Your observation looks pretty on point to me. It also doesn't look like there's a good way to change this undocumented behavior without filing a ticket with Microsoft.

Why would they put that seemingly artificial limitation in there? This line looks revealing enough:

```cs
_dueTimeInTicks = Environment.TickCount + (int)_interval.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Why refactor code to address corner cases when you can just validate the input and close the ticket? :)